# Why does relative path fail on Bamboo?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bamboo

My relative path fails on Bamboo.

I have a Visual Basic 2015 project (C#) with VS unit test.

I have my PROJ.Test project with a folder labeled 'TestData'.

In my code I create a `string filepath = @"TestData\testfile.xml"`.

This all works fine locally. The files are set **Copy to Output Directory**. In addition on Bamboo I have a MSTest Runner task, with Container set to `PROJ.Test\bin\Debug\PROJ.Test.dll`.

My expectation would be for the unit test to run from `[build-dir\PROJ-JobX\PROJ.Test\bin\Debug]` and find the relative TestData folder.

Instead Bamboo is looking in `[build-dir\PROJ-JobX\svcbamboo_Server Date\Out\TestData]` for these files and failing.

Why is it not looking in the expected location? and more importantly how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

So I never got an explaination on what creates the new folder path identified, but we did resolve the issue by use of Deployment Items (as identified [here](https://robor78.wordpress.com/2016/07/04/add-a-deployment-item-to-a-c-unit-test/). Once we utilized that it identified the path for Unit Test regardless of location and worked on Bamboo.